# Multiple database queries with get request

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, node.js, postgresql

Is there a way i can make multiple database queries with one GET request?

Currently, I have this GET request that returns data about employees:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/employees',
    success: function(employees) {
        console.log(employees)
    }
});
```

On the server side, it returns employee data:

```
router.get('/employees', function(req, res, next) {
knex('employees').where({
    current: true
}).then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
   });
});
```

However, I want to make a second database query to return another set of data to the client.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: if you have two "database managers" classes where you handle both data sources - yes, you can; P.S. you have not specified `"server side"` logic at all.

Comment: I guess he has only one database, just wants to query database twice and combine two data sets in a single http response, am I right?

Comment: @xersiee - yes that's what I am trying to do. dmitry - by "server" i mean the application server.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one way to do it if you need to rely on output of first query to call another query and return it as one GET request from server:

```
router.get('/employees', function(req, res, next) {
knex('employees').where({
    current: true
}).then(function(data) {
    // Here, you can make another database query 
    // assuming that you need to use employees data in order to make another query
    var result = {employees : data};
    anotherModel.where({options}).then(function(childData){
      result.anotherModel = childData; 
        res.send(result);
    });

   });
});
```

Comment: would that work if my second query does NOT depend on the first query?

Comment: @JustinNguyen why would you want to make the first query if the second has no dependency on it?

Comment: Yes, it would still work if second query doesn't rely on first query. But at that point, you want to look into node async module and use that to make 2 different database queries and wait till both of them returns back before sending response back to client.